# Change Polymer 3 route to a different html page

Tags: javascript, rest, polymer-3.x

I am creating a sample Polymer 3 app with a login and dashboard page. My backend is a simple JX-RS REST API. Once I get a response from the web service, I want to go to a new HTML file (lets says `dashboard.html`) rather than route to a different element within the same page. When I go through the 
[official website](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/create-a-page), I could not really understand how to proceed as I am a beginner in JS itself.

In my `index.html`, I have `<my-login>`, after the response, `handlePositiveResponse` is called. This is the place where I am changing the route. Please find the method below.

Following is my code:
**login.js**

```
class MyLogin extends PolymerElement {
static get template() {
    return html`
    <h1>Hello World..!!</h1>
    <iron-form id="loginUserForm"  on-iron-form-response="handlePositiveResponse" on-iron-form-error="handleNegativeResponse">
            <form id="innerLoginUserForm" content-type="application/json" method="post">
                <paper-input id="email" name="email"  label="E-Mail Address"></paper-input>
                <paper-input id="password" name="password" label="Password" type="password"></paper-input>
                <paper-button disabled="{{activeRequest}}" raised id="loginButton" on-tap="submitLogin">Sign In</paper-button>
            </form>
    </iron-form>
    `;
}

static get properties() {
    return {
        page: {
            type: String,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            observer: '_pageChanged'
        },
        routeData: Object,
        subroute: Object
    };
}

static get observers() {
    return [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
    ];
}

_routePageChanged(page) {
    // Show the corresponding page according to the route.
    //
    // If no page was found in the route data, page will be an empty string.
    // Show 'view1' in that case. And if the page doesn't exist, show 'view404'.
    if (!page) {
        this.page = 'login';
    } else if (['view1', 'view2', 'view3', 'my-dashboard'].indexOf(page) !== -1) {
        this.page = page;
    } else {
        this.page = 'view404';
    }

    // Close a non-persistent drawer when the page & route are changed.
    // if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
    //   this.$.drawer.close();
    // }
}

_pageChanged(page) {
    // Import the page component on demand.
    //
    // Note: `polymer build` doesn't like string concatenation in the import
    // statement, so break it up.
    switch (page) {
        case 'view1':
            import('./my-view1.js');
            break;
        case 'view2':
            import('./my-view2.js');
            break;
        case 'view3':
            import('./my-view3.js');
            break;
        case 'my-dashboard':
            import('./my-dashboard.js');
            break;
        case 'view404':
            import('./my-view404.js');
            break;
    }
}

submitLogin(e) {
    var form = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#loginUserForm');
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#innerLoginUserForm').action = 'http://localhost:8080/PolymerJavaBackend/rest/login'
    form.submit();
}

handlePositiveResponse(response) {
    this._routePageChanged(null);
    this._routePageChanged('my-dashboard');
    console.log(response);
}

handleNegativeResponse(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Would appreciate, if you could advise, how to route to a new html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that your top-level element? Is in your top-level element, where you should have the **iron-pages** element with all the pages you have in your app, and where you must add the new page.

There you should have the _routePageChanged to check the route data changes. And _pageChanged to import the page.

If you want to navigate to your new page, not from menu, but when you'd get response from the server, in **handlePositiveResponse(response)**,  you can use the two-way databinding or this.set to update the route value: `this.set('route.path', '/my-dashboard');`

Comment: yes, it did work. Well, I was struggling a bit with Observers as how it was working. Well, its now solved. Thanks. :)